# Understanding basic functions properties (domain , odd , monotone and image) $f(x)=\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}$

Tags: calculus, functions

> Let $f(x)=\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}$
>
> find the domain
>
> prove that the function is odd
>
> prove that the function is monotone increasing
>
> find the image of the function

---

the domain is $1+x \geq0$ and $1-x \geq 0$ so $x \in [-1,1]$

for odd  we need to prove $f(-x)=-f(x)$ so $\sqrt{1+(-x)}-\sqrt{1-(-x)} = -(\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x})=-f(x)$

a function is monotone increasing if  for every point $x_1 \leq x_2$ we get $f(x_1) \leq f(x_2)$
so assuming $x_1 \leq x_2$
$f(x)=\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x}}{\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x}}$

$f(x)=\frac{2x}{\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1-x}}$

this is where I got stuck.. I need to prove $f(x_1)=\frac{2x_1}{\sqrt{1+x_1}+\sqrt{1-x_1}} \leq \frac{2x_2}{\sqrt{1+x_2}+\sqrt{1-x_2}}=f(x_2)$

but how can I do that ? the only thing I know is that $\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}} \leq\frac{2x_1}{\sqrt{1+x_1}+\sqrt{1-x_1}} \leq \frac{2x_2}{\sqrt{1+x_2}+\sqrt{1-x_2}} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

I tried calculating the image by $y=\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x}$ and it did not work

EDIT - I am not allowed to use derivative or any advanced method, just by basic definitions

Thanks for any tips and help

Comment: Yes, I misread the thrust of your posting.  So, I deleted my answer.

Comment: I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addendum added to respond to the comment of Adamrk.

---

Easier approach to proving that the function is strictly increasing is to prove that the derivative is always $~> 0,~$ for all $~x~$ such that $-1 \leq x \leq 1.$

Assume that

$$f(x) = \sqrt{1+x} - \sqrt{1-x}. \tag1 $$

Then

$$f'(x) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{1+x}} - \left[\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-x}} \times (-1)\right] = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{1+x}} + \frac{1}{2\sqrt{1-x}} > 0.$$

Since the function is strictly increasing, and since the function is continuous, you know that the range of the function is all values $y$ such that

$$-\sqrt{2} = f(-1) \leq y \leq f(1) = \sqrt{2}.$$

---

**Addendum**

Responding to the comment of Adamrk:

The challenge is to prove that

$$f(x) = \sqrt{1+x} - \sqrt{1-x} $$

is strictly increasing on the interval $~-1 \leq x \leq 1~$ without using derivatives.

The approach that the OP (i.e. original poster) attempted makes sense to me.

So, assume that $-1 \leq x_1 < x_2 \leq 1.$

**To show**
$f(x_1) < f(x_2).$

This means that you have to show that

$$\sqrt{1+x_1} - \sqrt{1-x_1} < \sqrt{1+x_2} - \sqrt{1-x_2}. \tag2 $$

This can be shown by separately showing the following:

- $\displaystyle \sqrt{1 + x_1} < \sqrt{1 + x_2}.$
- $\displaystyle \sqrt{1 - x_1} > \sqrt{1 - x_2}.$

If both of the bullet points above are shown, then the inequality in (2) above is implied.

First, I will prove a preliminary result:

**PR-1**
$~\displaystyle 0 \leq y < z \leq 2 \implies \sqrt{y} < \sqrt{z}.$
**Proof**
I will use the principle that if $r \geq s,$ then 
$r \times a \geq s \times a$, when $r,a,s$ are all non-negative. 
Suppose instead that $~\displaystyle \sqrt{y} \geq \sqrt{z}.$ 
Then $\displaystyle ~\sqrt{y} \times \sqrt{y} \geq \sqrt{y} \times \sqrt{z} \geq \sqrt{z} \times \sqrt{z}.$ 
This implies that $\displaystyle ~y = \sqrt{y}\times \sqrt{y} \geq \sqrt{z} \times \sqrt{z} = z.$ 
This contradicts the assumption that $y < z.$

Take the bullet points one at a time:

---

**To show**

$\displaystyle \sqrt{1 + x_1} < \sqrt{1 + x_2}.$

Let $y = 1 + x_1$ and let $z = 1 + x_2$.

Then, you have that $0 \leq y < z \leq 2.$

Invoke **PR-1**.

---

**To show**

$\displaystyle \sqrt{1 - x_1} > \sqrt{1 - x_2}.$

Let $z = 1 - x_1$ and let $y = 1 - x_2$.

Then, you have that $0 \leq y < z \leq 2.$

Invoke **PR-1**.

Comment: appreciate the help but I am still very new so I can only use the super basic stuff cannot use the derivative I should've pointed it out

Comment: @Adamrk See the Addendum that I have just added to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $x > y$. Then,
\begin{align*}
f(x) - f(y) = &\sqrt{1+x}-\sqrt{1-x} - \sqrt{1+y}+ \sqrt{1-y}\\
=& \frac{1+x-1-y}{\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1+y}}+\frac{1-y-1+x}{\sqrt{1-x}+\sqrt{1-y}}\\
=& (x-y)\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x}+\sqrt{1+y}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}+\sqrt{1-y}} \right) > 0
\end{align*}

Regarding the image, since $f$ is increasing, you have that
$$
f([-1,1]) = [f(-1), f(1)] = [-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}].
$$

Answer (score 2):

By squaring the given function, we have:

$$y^2=2-2\sqrt {1-x^2}$$

Therefore, we can define the equivalent function as follows:

$$\begin{align}f(x)&:=\begin{cases}\sqrt {2}\cdot\sqrt{1-\sqrt {1-x^2}},~\text{if}~~0≤x≤1\\
-\sqrt{2}\cdot\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}},~\text{if}~~-1≤x<0\end{cases}\end{align}$$

You can complete your analysis, since all points seem straightforward. Indeed, we see that the function

$$g(x)=\sqrt 2\cdot\sqrt{1-\sqrt {1-x^2}}$$ is strictly increasing, when $0≤x≤1$ and $g(x)\in \left[0,\sqrt 2\right]$.

Similarly, the function

$$g(x)=-\sqrt 2\cdot\sqrt{1-\sqrt {1-x^2}}$$ is strictly increasing, when $-1≤x<0$ and $g(x)\in\left[-\sqrt 2,0\right)$.

This completes the answer.